# How can fetch data with swap column

Tags: php

I already get all data but I don't know how to fetch data with switch column for ex 1st data in left img in right , 2 nd data in right img in left( display will be in like my html )

Here is My php

```
$SQL            =   "SELECT * FROM DB_NEWS";
$result         =   mysql_query($SQL);
while ($row     =   mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $data       =   $row["DATA"];
    $img        =   $row["IMG"];
```

Here is my HTML ( I want data to fetch like this )

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/ >
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div style="height:150px;background-color: red"> $data</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div style="height:150px;background-color: blue">$img</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div style="height:150px;background-color: blue"> $img</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div style="height:150px;background-color: red">$data</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have printed two $data and $img, is it same or from different row from database?

Comment: same row sir @tan

Comment: $data in left col-6 $img in right col-6 , the 2 nd data shd swap $img left $data right but in same row

Comment: "the 2 nd data" means 2nd row in db, right?

Comment: yes sir, ,  @tan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the four div as a combination of 2 div. Use a counter with mod operator to match first two div or 2nd two div you are dealing with.

```
$i = 0 ;
while ($row     =   mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if( $i++ % 2 == 0 ) {
    $col1       =   $row["DATA"];
    $col2        =   $row["IMG"];
    $color1     = 'blue' ;
    $color2     = 'red' ;
    }
    else {
    $col1       =   $row["IMG"];
    $col2        =   $row["IMG"];
    $color1     = 'red' ;
    $color2     = 'blue' ;

    }
?>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div style="height:150px;background-color: <?php echo $color1;?>"><?php $col1;?></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div style="height:150px;background-color: <?php echo $color2;?>"><?php $col2;?></div>
</div>

<?
php 
} //end of while
?>
```

Logic:
It will print two div at a time. when the loop begin $i is zero. 0 %2 will result in 0; so first data will be printed. after that $++ will will make it 1. when the next time loop comes 1%2 is != 0 so else part will be considerd.

Comment: Can you explain more what is  if( $i++ % 2 == 0 )  mean ?

Comment: If in 2nd row i've different Css what shd i do ? ex 1st row, float:right . 2nd row  float:left

Comment: edited the answer for color value. if you have so many changes, copy the html itself into if and else part. so you can make as many change without much variables.

Answer (score 1):

Have you reviewed PHP syntax?

Rather than saving your file as .html, save it as .php. You can write HTML exactly the same, but have the added benefit of being able to use PHP as well. Then you can do this:

```
<?php
// You can start the file in PHP

$SQL            =   "SELECT * FROM DB_NEWS";
$result         =   mysql_query($SQL);
while ($row     =   mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $data       =   $row["DATA"];
    $img        =   $row["IMG"];
?>

<!-- Now we are in HTML, but still hop back into PHP to work with variables. -->

    <?foreach ($row as mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ):?>
        <? $data = $row['DATA'];
           $img = $row['IMG'];
        ?>
        <div> 
            <div> <? echo $data ?> </div>
            <div> <? echo $img ?> </div>
        </div>
    <? endforeach ?>
```

Comment: How can i display like in my html ?

Comment: Add your classes where you want them. The `echo` function prints the variables to the page.

Comment: @user8663822 I see what you mean regarding classes. Add a variable, such as $color, and assign it based on the data. Then you can put it inline, for example: `<div style=" color: <? echo $color ?> "> . . .  </div>`

Answer (score 1):

If I was to write this, this is how I would do it.

Updated code to reflect your OP markup.

```
    <?php
    $SQL            =   "SELECT * FROM DB_NEWS";
    $result         =   mysql_query($SQL);
    // define variable
    $html = NULL;   
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       $html .= ''
        . '<div class="col-md-6">'
            . '<div style="height:150px;background-color: red">' . $row['DATA'] . '</div>'
        . '</div>'
        . '<div class="col-md-6">'
            . '<div style="height:150px;background-color: blue">' . $row['IMG'] . '</div>'
        . '</div>';
    }

    echo $html;
```